# HiddenFor complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

We have a notion of `CatalogValue` in our application which has the properties `ID` and `DisplayText` (among others).

We have a `TypeConverter` to allow the model binder to convert the ID to an instance of `CatalogValue` and all is fine so far.

However, when we do render a `HiddenFor` instead of an `EditorFor`, it does not work anymore, as the `value` of the hidden input field is `My.Namespace.SomeCatalogValueType` instead of the catalog value's ID. This sounds logical, as MVC cannot know that it should use the ID.

So, how to tell ASP.NET MVC to render the ID as the value? Is there an interface we must implement? Is it calling `ToString()`?

At the moment we have this quirky workaround, we would like to replace:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].BrennstoffArt, htmlAttributes: new { Value = @Model[i].BrennstoffArt.Id })
```

where `BrennstoffArt` is a property of type `BrennstoffArtCatalogValue`.